# How to use urllib to download a partial HTML file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

I'm trying to download a bunch of HTML pages using urllib on Python 3.7, and then parse them using Beautifulsoup. However, the files are very large, so they take too long to download.

I only need data that exists within the first half of the documents, so I was wondering if there was a way to download only the first half of the pages? From my research, I found out that we can use something called range headers to download files partially (based on bytes), but this seems to only work in urllib2 for Python 2. I was having a hard time finding information about this for Python 3, which is why I wanted to as here.

Also, I'm using urllib instead of requests module because it seems that urllib is much faster. If anyone can suggest an even faster module (maybe urllib3?), I'd appreciate it!.